# Не могу подключить стороннюю библеотеку Docxtemplater для JS

Tags: javascript, html

Я пытаюсь сделать сайт. Суть простая - есть несколько полей для ввода. В папку где находится HTML и CSS файлы залит шаблон в формате docx. При нажатии на кнопку Go , мне выдается ссылка для скачивания файла, где были предварительно расставлены специальные метки,но теперь они заменены на те данные, которые я вводил в инпутах. я подключил библиотеку Docxtemplater. но мой скрипт не работает, консоль выдает ошибку :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Docxtemplater is not defined
> onload http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html:42

Хотя библиотека должна работать, так как я проверял эту ссылку вручную. (ссылку взял с сайта cdnjs)
Подскажите, что можно сделать ? Ниже пример кода

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form class="main__form">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name">
        <br>
        <label for="second_name">Second</label>
        <input type="text" id="second_name">
        <br>
        <label for="number">Number</label>
        <input type="text" id="number">
        <br>
        <button type="button" id="generate">GO</button>
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jszip@3.7.1/dist/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/docxtemplater/3.37.1/docxtemplater.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', function () {

            let nameValue = document.getElementById('name').value;
            let second_nameValue = document.getElementById('second_name').value;
            let numberValue = document.getElementById('number').value;

            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', 'docx.docx', true);
            xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

            xhr.onload = function () {
                const zip = new JSZip();
                const content = xhr.response;
                const template = new Docxtemplater();
                zip.loadAsync(content).then(function (zip) {
                    const doc = zip.file('word/document.xml').asText();
                    template.loadXml(doc);
                    template.setData({
                        name: nameValue,
                        second_name: second_nameValue,
                        number: numberValue,
                    });
                    template.render();
                    const updatedDoc = template.getZip().generate({
                        type: 'blob'
                    });

                    const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
                    downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(updatedDoc);
                    downloadLink.download = 'result.docx';
                    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
                    downloadLink.click();
                });
            };

            xhr.send();
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```